# Issue uploading CodeCov file after running "Very Good Workflows" in my GitHub workflow

Tags: flutter, github-actions, code-coverage, cicd

I an using the [very_good_workflows](https://verygood.ventures/blog/configuring-workflows-for-your-flutter-projects) action to recursively run tests on my app and all the local packages contained in the project.

I want to generate and upload a codeCov file after all the tests are run, but I get the error that no such file exits.

This is my current setup:

```yaml
name: Flutter CI

# This workflow is triggered on pushes and pull requests to the repository.
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build:
    # Install very good cli
    uses: VeryGoodOpenSource/very_good_workflows/.github/workflows/flutter_package.yml@v1
    with:
      coverage_excludes: '*.g.dart *.freezed.dart'
      flutter_channel: 'stable'
      flutter_version: "3.13.x"
      test_recursion: true
      min_coverage: 70

  visualize:
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      # Check out repository
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      # Setup the flutter environment
      - uses: subosito/flutter-action@v2
        with:
          channel: "stable"
          flutter-version: "3.13.x"

      # Upload coverage report to Codecov
      - name: Upload coverage report to Codecov
        uses: codecov/codecov-action@v3
        env:
          CODECOV_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.MY_CODECOV_TOKEN }}
```

Has anyone had any success with uploading code coverage files to codecov after a successful very good workflow run?

Comment: _"I get the error that no such file [exists]"_ - because the reusable workflow runs in a separate job. Jobs don't share state, only steps within the same job can access those files, unless they're explicitly stored somewhere by `build` and downloaded back into `visualize`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe This make sense. Is there a way to add steps to a reusable workflow. When I first tried to run the very good workflow as a step I got an error saying reusable workflows cannot have steps.

Comment: _"Is there a way to add steps to a reusable workflow"_ - not as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `build` and `visualize` jobs are run in different runners.

The [reusable workflow](https://github.com/VeryGoodOpenSource/very_good_workflows/blob/main/.github/workflows/flutter_package.yml) that you're using checks out your repo, installs deps, runs tests, calculates code coverage, etc., but it doesn't upload the coverage file. So, the generated coverage file remains on the runner used to run your `build` job.

One possible solution could be to run all these [steps](https://github.com/VeryGoodOpenSource/very_good_workflows/blob/main/.github/workflows/flutter_package.yml) in your own workflow and add the upload step at the end of that.

You may leverage the mechanism of [passing data between jobs in a workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/storing-workflow-data-as-artifacts#passing-data-between-jobs-in-a-workflow) as artifacts if you decide to divide your workflow in multiple jobs.

Comment: One issue with this us that I can't add steps to a reusable workflow, so I don't understand how I would be able to upload the artifacts. By "run all these steps in your own workflow" do you mean replacing the very good workflow with my own implementation?

Comment: @JoelBroström: You can copy those steps in your workflow as a quick fix. Apart from that, you might want to open an issue on that repo to add this functionality out of the box too.

Comment: @JoelBroström: You're welcome! Just found these issues for a similar feature request. See https://github.com/VeryGoodOpenSource/very_good_workflows/issues/42 and https://github.com/VeryGoodOpenSource/very_good_coverage/issues/178. You might want to update these instead of creating new ones.